How effective is the LIFO strategy in Reactor Netty's connection pool for multi-host WebClient scenarios?
I'm working with Reactor Netty and have configured maxIdleTimeout to minimize connection drops during network communication. The LIFO (Last In, First Out) strategy is designed to efficiently manage connections by reusing the most recently used connection. My understanding is that if the most recent connection drops, it might indicate that earlier connections could also be stale, which helps in managing the connection pool more effectively.
However, I'm dealing with a scenario where multiple WebClient instances share the same connection pool while communicating with different external servers:
When the connection pool is shared across multiple hosts, a dropped LIFO connection doesn’t necessarily mean that all connections to other hosts are also disconnected. This makes me question whether the LIFO strategy is still effective in such a multi-host environment, as the assumptions around connection reuse might not hold.

Is the LIFO strategy still efficient when the connection pool is shared across multiple WebClient instances communicating with different external hosts?
How does the LIFO strategy handle connections in a scenario involving multiple hosts?
Would it be more effective to separate connection pools by host, or to use a different connection reuse strategy (e.g., FIFO or an adaptive strategy) when dealing with multiple hosts?


https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/3408
